# Display products that belongs to a specific category in WooCommerce My account

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to display products of a specific product category Id (id=129) from customer order, if product id is 2847. I'm trying to display it on the customer's account page.

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_content', 'check_order_product_id' );
      
function check_order_product_id( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items(); 

    foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item ) {
       $product_id = $item->get_variation_id() ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id();
       if ( $product_id === 2847 ) {
           // display products
           $args = array(
               'post_type'             => 'product',
               'post_status'           => 'publish',
               'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
               'posts_per_page'        => '12',
               'tax_query'             => array( 
                    array(
                        'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
                        'field' => 'term_id',
                        'terms'         => 129,
                        'operator'      => 'IN' 
                    ),
                    array(
                        'taxonomy'      => 'product_visibility',
                        'field'         => 'slug',
                        'terms'         => 'exclude-from-catalog',
                        'operator'      => 'NOT IN'
                    )
                )
            );
            $products = new WP_Query($args);
            var_dump($products);
        }
    }
}
```

Why this code is not working ?

Comment: Because `$order_id` is not defined with `woocommerce_account_content` hook…